# Nested for and do while loop

Tags: php, loops

How do i create a nested loop that will output the following numbers?
each round the inner loop increase from 1 to 5, 5 to 10 and so on.

from i = 0 to 5
    inner loop:
     result: 1 2 3 4 5
 
      result: 6 7 8 9 1 0
       result: 11 12 13 14 15
 
        result: 16 17 18 19 20
  next

```
for($i=0;$i<50;$i++)
{
$s = $i +5;
echo $s;
}
```

Comment: `How do i create a nested loop that will output the following numbers.` By actually doing it. You have it already laid out for you. Just implement it. Once you have some code and still have problems, then write your question.

Comment: @NicolásCarlo i tried, i'm stuck.

Comment: ` i'm stuck`. Where's the code?

Comment: as you can can see i just dont get it.

Answer (score 1):

unless you have to use an inner `do...while` loop, this will work:

```
<?php
$max = 5;
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    for($j=1;$j<=$max;$j++){
        echo str_pad(($i*$max)+$j,4);
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   
6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  
16  17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24  25
```

I used str_pad() just to make the columns more uniform